# redirect from checking password

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very basic website with the idea of a quick and easy way to quickly send to a page and I don't know how to do that.

so I have:

```
<form class="passform" action="" onsubmit="return passcheck()">
    password: <input type="password" required id="pass1">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

in the HTML with the flowing in js

```
var password = "%Password%";
const submit = document.getElementById("pass1")



function passcheck () {
    if(submit.value != password) {
        alert('Wrong Password, Try Again.')
        return false
    }
}  

function passcheck () {
    if(submit.value == password) {
        
    alert('Correct Pasword, lets go')
    window.location.href="/pic/index.html";
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to return nothing, just redirect if is equal and print message if not, like:

```js
var password = "%Password%";
const submit = document.getElementById("pass1");
function passcheck() {
  if (submit.value == password) {
    alert('Correct Pasword, lets go')
    window.location.href = "/pic/index.html";
  } else {
    alert('Wrong Password, Try Again.')
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="passform" action="" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();passcheck()">
  password: <input type="password" required id="pass1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I simple add `event.preventDefault()` (i change inline method with `EventListener`) for prevent submit and check `if` password is equal continue `else` print message

The real question is, Are you sure of this method? is insecure.

Comment: i am ok with it as it is just for testing before we try to redesign it but just for quick test

Comment: i tried the code you had and it still reloaded sadly and the problem of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Have you more then 1 form into page? because `const form = document.querySelector("form");` is for one form, instead use `const form = document.querySelector("#ID");`

Comment: try this(i change into answer)

Comment: I think that would work but can not check yet

Comment: Ok try if it's all ok mark answer thanks :)

Comment: you get a response of a null but was fixed and all good